# What is the best Eclipse distribution for a mix of Java and Web?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Basically, I want to mix in Java and Web (JavaScript, CSS, HTML, PHP, .NET, etc..) into one. So what is the best IDE for that?

Since I'm a huge fan of Eclipse, I'd like to move from Dreamweaver to Eclipse for my Web Development. I love using Eclipse for Java development but I want to be able to maintain the functionality of Dreamweaver in Eclipse... so I want to incorporate the [Web Tools Platform](http://eclipse.org/webtools/) into my environment.

What is the difference between ***Eclipse IDE for Java Developers*** and ***Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers***? Could I do Java and Web with Eclipse and if I can, is it done with either of the above 2 packages?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend changing the title of this question to "What is the best Eclipse distro for PHP Development?"

Comment: @Alain That's not what the OP is asking for, he explicitly wrote he wants to mix Java and Web development.

Comment: @Pascal... thank you for your support, however, I do agree I should change the title.

Comment: The new title is much better.  My answer would have been different too.  I missed the Java point entirely here.  I think starting with the PDT and using Eclipse Marketplace to install the Java Development Tools is the best option.  I don't know of any pre-rolled Eclipse distro that does Java and PHP out of the box.

Comment: @Alain... Thanks. I'm not looking for PHP specifically... actually JavaScript more so than anything. But Web support is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between ***Eclipse IDE for Java Developers*** and ***Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers***?

Actually, there is a [comparison of all packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) on Eclipse website. In short, ***Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers*** is targeted at server side development and extends ***Eclipse IDE for Java Developers*** by including the following additional packages:

- [**Web Tools**](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) - server-side development support
- [Java EE Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)
- [RSE](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm) (Remote System Explorer) - remote (mainframe down to embedded) systems support
- [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/tm) - JPA support
- [PDE](http://www.eclipse.org/pde/) - for plugin development
- [Datatools](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/) - database support

> (...) so I want to incorporate the [Web Tools Platform](http://eclipse.org/webtools/) into my environment.

It is part of of ***Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers***. If you decide to go for ***Eclipse IDE for Java Developers***, you'll have to add it.

> Basically, I want to mix in Java and Web (PHP, JavaScript, CSS, HTML, etc..) into one. Could I do that with Eclipse and if I can, is it done with either of the above 2 packages?

I would get ***Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers*** (for simplicity sake) and install [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) on top of it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm sure the information to answer my question is out there but what you did in a couple of paragraphs is exactly what I'm looking for... brief and to the point. I wish I could give you several upvotes :)

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse PHP Development Tools has all-in-one downloads available here :) http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/

Make sure to download and install the PHP debugger from that page as well to get the integrated debug working in Eclipse.

I was a die-hard Eclipse fan for years.  I used Eclipse since 1.0 and on through to Eclipse 3.4.  I was obliged to switch to IntelliJ at work as part of standardization.  I have found that IntelliJ has *much* better support for web development.

I suspect that JetBrains PHPStorm http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/ is probably a very good web development environment based on my experience with IntelliJ for JSF.  The JetBrains guys know how to make a good User Experience.

Comment: do you know of PDT has JavaScript support... like syntax highlight, bracket matching, auto-complete, etc...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Yoxos - http://eclipsesource.com/en/yoxos/yoxos-ondemand/ to customize your need.